# How to Determine which Fragment called the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have 2 Fragments that both pass an intent to an Activity (through an event listener). How can the Activity know which of these 2 fragments passed the intent? There's a method called `getCallingActivity()`, I need the equivalent for fragments.

I Attempted to determine which Fragment Called the Activity with the `onAttachFragment()` method, But it doesn't work:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {
    static final String POSITION = "position";
    private Movie movie;
    private int position;
    private static final String TAG = "app";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        Log.v(TAG, "fragment_src");
        position = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get(POSITION);
        if (fragment instanceof PopularFragment) {
            movie = PopularFragment.movieList.get(position);
            setData();
        } else if (fragment instanceof TopRatedFragment) {
            movie = TopRatedFragment.movieList.get(position);
            setData();
        }
    }

    public void setData() {
        TextView original_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.original_title);
        original_title.setText(movie.getOriginal_title());
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send different int values with your intent for both fragment and check in your activity..or you could get your fragment by using

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourtag");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass some parameters through the Intent itself

For first fragment-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fragName","PopularFragment");
startActivity(intent);
```

For Second Fragment-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fragName","TopRatedFragment");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your Activity

```
String fragName=getIntent().getStringExtra("fragName");
```

And then just check using if..else.